# NULL == 0 in MySql?

Tags: mysql, null, operators, where-clause

I use query like this:
    `SELECT table.field FROM table WHERE table.field > 0`
Would `WHERE` clause be working if `table.field` contain `NULL` value?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `field` is null? Include in results or not?

Comment: not need to include if `field` contain `NULL`

Comment: you can just check  `SELECT NULL  = 0;`

Comment: your query already does that: A null value is not true for any comparison other than by `is null` and `is not null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` clause will work the way it is supposed to.  Just about all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`, which is treated as "false" in the `where` clause.

So, all these expressions will return no rows if the value is `NULL`:

```
WHERE table.field > 0
WHERE table.field = 0
WHERE table.field < 0
WHERE table.field <> 0
```

If you are concerned about `NULL` values, test for them explicitly (using `is null` or `is not null`) or use a function like `coalesce()` to give the field a value when it is `NULL`.

Comment: Do we have some way to CAST NULL into boolean in MySQL? I tried but couldn't find.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan . . . You don't need to cast it.  Just say `field is not null` and MySQL gives a boolean result, which is "true" (1) if the field is not null and "false" (0) if the field is.

Comment: Ok, I got it, I tried `> SET @a = NULL; SELECT @a is NULL;` thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to be sure.

```
 SELECT table.field FROM table WHERE table.field > 0
                               AND table.field is not null
```

Comment: -1 the test for `is not null` adds no value, since the original test for `> 0` will not be true if `field` is null.

Comment: but now it will return every non-null row, eg if `field` is `-1` it will be returned: That hardly makes sense if the original test was for `field > 0`. You are barking up the wrong tree.